# Remove Validation error message before onClick if it satisfies the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I want to remove the error message if it satisfies the condition before onClick function. Now it remove the error message onClick function if it satisfies the condition. Need Help. Thanks in advance

```
$('.msf-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {  

var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');

var next_step = true;

if (!$('input[name="abc"]:checked').val()) {

$(".error-messages-abc").html("<img src='assets/img/er2.png'> 

Please Select").fadeIn();

next_step = false;

} 

else {

 $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut();

     }

 if( next_step ) {

        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {

            $(this).next().fadeIn();

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you add a few words to describe the issue in the question?

Comment: edit the question. Pl check and advise.

Comment: If I understood your issue correctly, have a change event for the checkbox/radio - `$('input[name="abc"]').change(function(){   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {  $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut(); });`

Comment: No its not working

Comment: What is not working? is that event being hit? If those elements are not in the DOM on DOM ready, then you gotta use `.on` for binding change event

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding on change function of checkbox and check the same condition you have used after click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="abc"]').on("change",function(){
        if(!$('input[name="abc"]:checked').val()){
            $(".error-messages-abc").html("<img src='assets/img/er2.png'> 
            Please Select").fadeIn();
            //Just check validation in this function
            //next_step = false;
        }else{
            $(".error-messages-abc").empty().fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

This will directly give you a result or error message as required before calling onclick function, so please have a look and let me know if this is working or not.

Comment: Actually i am using this in step form its validate onclick next button. After using your function its going on next step without validating

Comment: you have to remove `next_step = false ` line here